# Discord.js v14 - serverinfo slash command not functioning / string issue?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I'm building a `serverinfo` slash command with an embed builder for my discord bot however I'm coming across this error which may be due to my `.addFields` section of my code. The following is the error I get when testing the command:

```
CombinedPropertyError (5)
  Received one or more errors

  input[1]
  | CombinedPropertyError (1)
  |   Received one or more errors
  | 
  |   input.value
  |   | ValidationError > s.string
  |   |   Expected a string primitive
  |   | 
  |   |   Received:
  |   |   | 16

  input[2]
  | CombinedPropertyError (1)
  |   Received one or more errors
  | 
  |   input.value
  |   | ValidationError > s.string
  |   |   Expected a string primitive
  |   | 
  |   |   Received:
  |   |   | 1

  input[3]
  | CombinedPropertyError (1)
  |   Received one or more errors
  | 
  |   input.value
  |   | ValidationError > s.string
  |   |   Expected a string primitive
  |   | 
  |   |   Received:
  |   |   | 5

  input[4]
  | CombinedPropertyError (1)
  |   Received one or more errors
  | 
  |   input.value
  |   | ValidationError > s.string
  |   |   Expected a string primitive
  |   | 
  |   |   Received:
  |   |   | 2

  input[5]
  | CombinedPropertyError (1)
  |   Received one or more errors
  | 
  |   input.value
  |   | ValidationError > s.string
  |   |   Expected a string primitive
  |   | 
  |   |   Received:
  |   |   | 2

    at ArrayValidator.handle (/home/runner/tester/node_modules/@sapphire/shapeshift/dist/index.js:468:70)
    at ArrayValidator.parse (/home/runner/tester/node_modules/@sapphire/shapeshift/dist/index.js:207:88)
    at EmbedBuilder.addFields (/home/runner/tester/node_modules/@discordjs/builders/dist/index.js:222:31)
    at Object.execute (/home/runner/tester/commands/info/serverinfo.js:21:8)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
```

I have no idea what it could be at this point. Here is the code I have written:

```js
const {
  SlashCommandBuilder,
  EmbedBuilder
} = require("discord.js");

  module.exports = {
    data: new SlashCommandBuilder()
      .setName("serverinfo")
      .setDescription("Provides information about the server.")
      .setDMPermission(false),
  
    async execute(client, interaction) {
      const { guild } = interaction;
      const { members, channels, emojis, roles, stickers } = guild;
  
      const embed = new EmbedBuilder()
        .setColor("#2B2D31")
        .setTitle(`${guild.name} - Server info`)
        .setThumbnail(guild.iconURL({ size: 256 }))
        .setImage(guild.bannerURL({ size: 256 }))
        .addFields(
          { name: "Owner", value: (await guild.fetchOwner()).user.tag, inline: true },
          { name: "Text Channels", value: guild.channels.cache.filter((c) => c.type === 0).toJSON().length, inline: true },
          { name: "Voice Channels", value: guild.channels.cache.filter((c) => c.type === 2).toJSON().length, inline: true },
          { name: "Category Channels", value: guild.channels.cache.filter((c) => c.type === 4).toJSON().length, inline: true },
          { name: "Members", value: guild.memberCount, inline: true },
          { name: "Roles", value: guild.roles.cache.size, inline: true },
          { name: "Role List", value: guild.roles.cache.toJSON().join(', ')},
        );
      interaction.reply({ embeds: [embed] });
    },
  };
```

Any ideas? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is pretty straight-forward. Field values should be string primitives but you provide numbers. All those `.length` properties, `guild.memberCount` and `cache.size` are numbers.

To fix this, you'll need to convert them to strings. Also, you don't need to use `toJSON()` as `filter()` returns a collection, you can use the `size` property instead:

```js
const embed = new EmbedBuilder()
  .setColor('#2B2D31')
  .setTitle(`${guild.name} - Server info`)
  .setThumbnail(guild.iconURL({ size: 256 }))
  .setImage(guild.bannerURL({ size: 256 }))
  .addFields(
    { name: 'Owner', value: (await guild.fetchOwner()).user.tag, inline: true },
    {
      name: 'Text Channels',
      value: guild.channels.cache.filter((c) => c.type === 0).size.toString(),
      inline: true,
    },
    {
      name: 'Voice Channels',
      value: guild.channels.cache.filter((c) => c.type === 2).size.toString(),
      inline: true,
    },
    {
      name: 'Category Channels',
      value: guild.channels.cache.filter((c) => c.type === 4).size.toString(),
      inline: true,
    },
    { name: 'Members', value: guild.memberCount.toString(), inline: true },
    { name: 'Roles', value: guild.roles.cache.size.toString(), inline: true },
    { name: 'Role List', value: guild.roles.cache.toJSON().join(', ') },
  );
```

You could also use template literals like this if you prefer them:

```js
{
  name: 'Text Channels',
  value: `${guild.channels.cache.filter((c) => c.type === 0).size}`,
  inline: true,
},
// ...
```